# Timing algorithm: clock() vs time() in C++

Tags: c++, clock, timing

For timing an algorithm (approximately in ms), which of these two approaches is better:

```
clock_t start = clock();
algorithm();
clock_t end = clock();
double time = (double) (end-start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000.0;
```

Or,

```
time_t start = time(0);
algorithm();
time_t end = time(0);
double time = difftime(end, start) * 1000.0;
```

Also, from some discussion in the C++ channel at Freenode, I know clock has a very bad resolution, so the timing will be zero for a (relatively) fast algorithm. But, which has better resolution time() or clock()? Or is it the same?

Comment: You have the parameters in the wrong order for difftime

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It depends what you want: `time` measures the real time while `clock` measures the processing time taken by the current process.  If your process sleeps for any appreciable amount of time, or the system is busy with other processes, the two will be very different.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock

Comment: `clock` is also influenced by local parallelism. Using OpenMP with N threads will cause all `clock` return values to increase (approximately) N-times faster during parallel regions.

Answer (score 61):

`<chrono>` would be a better library if you're using C++11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void f()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}

int main()
{
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    f();
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "f() took "
              << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2-t1).count()
              << " milliseconds\n";
}
```

Example taken from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast).

Answer (score 10):

The time_t structure is probably going to be an integer, which means it will have a resolution of second.

The first piece of code: It will only count the time that the CPU was doing something, so when you do sleep(), it will not count anything. It can be bypassed by counting the time you sleep(), but it will probably start to drift after a while.

The second piece: Only resolution of seconds, not so great if you need sub-second time readings.

For time readings with the best resolution you can get, you should do something like this:

```
double getUnixTime(void)
{
    struct timespec tv;

    if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tv) != 0) return 0;

    return (tv.tv_sec + (tv.tv_nsec / 1000000000.0));
}

double start_time = getUnixTime();
double stop_time, difference;

doYourStuff();

stop_time = getUnixTime();
difference = stop_time - start_time;
```

On most systems it's resolution will be down to few microseconds, but it can vary with different CPUs, and probably even major kernel versions.

Comment: The explicit casts to `double` in the `return` line are superfluous since both arithmetic operators operate on at least one `double` argument (the literal, then the result of the division). Also you should use a more succinct literal notation: I consider `return tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_nsec / 1.0e9;` to be much more readable.

Comment: "so when you do sleep(), it will not count anything" is it true? I tested sleep, it is counted in clocks.

Answer (score 2):

`<chrono>` is the best. Visual Studio 2013 provides this feature. Personally, I have tried all the methods mentioned above. I strongly recommend you use the `<chrono>` library. It can track the wall time and at the same time have a good resolution (much less than a second).

Answer (score 0):

How about `gettimeofday()`? When it is called it updates two structs (`timeval` and `timezone`), with timing information. Usually, passing a `timeval` struct is enough and the `timezone` struct can be set to `NULL`. The updated `timeval` struct will have two members `tv_sec` and `tv_usec`. `tv_sec` is the number of seconds since 00:00:00, January 1, 1970 (Unix Epoch) and `tv_usec` is additional number of microseconds w.r.t. `tv_sec`. Thus, one can get time expressed in very good resolution.

It can be used as follows:

```
#include <time.h>

struct timeval start_time;
double mtime, seconds, useconds;
gettimeofday(&start_time, NULL); //timeval is usually enough
int seconds  = start_time.tv_sec; //time in seconds
int useconds = start_time.tv_usec; //further time in microseconds
int desired_time = seconds * 1000000 + useconds; //time in microseconds
```